# Ansible: insert string at the end of the line but only if string is not present OR/AND change value if present

Tags: linux, ansible, grub

I am struggling below scenario:

In */etc/default/grub* file, there is *GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT* stanza,
I need to insert **audit=1** at the end of the line **if value is not there already** *(note that there is quote char at the end of line)*. If *audit=0* is present change it to *audit=1*.

*lineinfile* ansible module does not work, especially with inserting before last quote (").

Original /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="rootfstype=xfs quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

Optional /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="rootfstype=xfs quiet splash acpi_osi= audit=0" # change audit=0 to audit=1
#OR:
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="rootfstype=xfs quiet splash acpi_osi= audit=1" # audit=1 is already here, so no action needed
```

Desired /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="rootfstype=xfs quiet splash acpi_osi= audit=1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a file where the text is audit=0 and tried to replace it with audit=1

my file was:
grubfile:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="rootfstype=xfs quiet splash acpi_osi= audit=0"
```

my playbook:

```
---
  - name: read grub file
    lineinfile:
      dest: /home/myhome/grubfile.txt
      regexp: '^(.*)audit=0(.*)$'
      line: '\1audit=1\2'
      backup: yes
      backrefs: yes
```

Basically we play with regexp taking the audit=1 as the regexp and storing the rest of the string with backrefs
the resulting file is:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="rootfstype=xfs quiet splash acpi_osi= audit=1"
```

Edit:
This code will add it even if doesn't exist, It will first modify if the audit=0 is present, then will check if audit=1 exists and if it doesn't exist will append the audit=1 to the beginning of the quotes :

```
---
  - name:
    lineinfile:
      dest: /home/mypath/grubfile.txt
      regexp: '^(.*)audit=1(.*)$'
      state: absent
    check_mode: yes
    changed_when: false
    register: auditexist
  - name: if audit=0 write audit=1
    lineinfile:
      dest: /home/mypath/grubfile.txt
      regexp: '^(.*)audit=0(.*)$'
      line: '\1audit=1\2'
      backup: yes
      backrefs: yes
    register: auditmodified
  - name: appen
    lineinfile:
     dest: /home/ivan/grubfile.txt
     regexp: '^(.*)GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="(.*)$'
     line: '\1GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="audit=1 \2 '
     backup: yes
     backrefs: yes
    when: not auditexist.found and not auditmodified.changed
```

result:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="audit=1 rootfstype=xfs quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

Comment: Thank you ikora!
But what when audit= is not present in the file?

Comment: It won't do anything, maybe I misunderstood you, if you always want to force to have audit=1 even if audit is not present maybe you can just replace the entire line for an entire line containing the audit=1

Comment: Yes, audit=1 needs to be in the file permanently. Cannot replace whole file as different systems has different grub config (Debian, Redhat, etc)

Comment: I will update the mu answer soon, I think I can do the trick, adding the audit=1 as the first parameter would work? something like w:GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="audit=1 rootfstype=xfs quiet splash acpi_osi="   this will work? or is mandatory that the rootfstype goes first? I'm sorry I don't have knowledge about grubfiles :D

Comment: Modified the answer with the outcome i suppose you want, try it.